# C logging input to file?

Tags: c, file, input

I'm working on a program that logs input to a file. This is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <signal.h>
#define WAIT 3
#define INCORRECT "Incorrect input\n"
#define FILENAME ".xintrc"

int stop();

int main()
{
    char first[10], last[10];
    int i;
    FILE *fp, *fopen()
    initscr();
    scanf("%[^\n]", first);
    getchar();
    noecho();
    scanf("%[^\n]", last);
    printf("\n");
    getchar();
    echo();
    sleep(WAIT);
    if((fp = fopen(FILENAME, "a")) != NULL){
    fprintf(fp, "First:   %s Last: %s\n", first, last);
    fclose(fp);
  }

    printf(INCORRECT);
    endwin();
 }
    stop()
 {
    endwin();
    exit(0);
 }
```

When I compile, I get this error:

```
input1.c: In function ‘main’:
input1.c:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘initscr’
input1.c: In function ‘stop’:
input1.c:35: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has quite a few problems.  See my embedded comments for a version that compiles and presumably does what you want in a more sane manner.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> /* for _Exit() */
#include <string.h> /* for strcspn() */
/* #include <curses.h> you don't need curses for such a simple program */
/* #include <signal.h> this header is not needed */

#define WAIT 3
#define INCORRECT "Incorrect input\n"
#define FILENAME "testfile"

void stop(void); /* match the new prototype */

int main(void) /* main() always returns int, use void if not using argc/argv */
{
  char first[10], last[10];
  /* int i;  You never use this */
  FILE *fp; /* You don't need *fopen() here */

  /* initscr(); */
  /* noecho(); */

  printf("Enter first name: "); /* Added by me */
  fgets(first, sizeof(first), stdin); /* Don't use scanf, fgets prevents overflows */
  first[strcspn(first,"\n")] = '\0'; /* chomp the newline if it exists */

  printf("Enter last name: "); /* Added by me */
  fgets(last, sizeof(last), stdin); /* Don't use scanf, fgets prevents overflows */
  last[strcspn(last,"\n")] = '\0'; /* chomp the newline if it exists */

  /* echo(); */
  sleep(WAIT);

  if((fp = fopen(FILENAME, "a")) != NULL){
    fprintf(fp, "First:   %s Last: %s\n", first, last);
    fclose(fp);
    stop(); /* You never call this, i'm guessing you want it here */
  }

  printf(INCORRECT); /* only called if fopen() fails */

  /* endwin(); */

  return 0; /* mandatory return for main() */
}

void stop(void) /* Use 'void' if the func takes no params and returns nothing */
{
  /* endwin(); */
  _Exit(0); /* _Exit is apart of C99 */
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks that worked perfectly :) The reason it was a fail was because I was using a different code from the 80's to help me.

Comment: @AustinM a few more comments. 1) The `sleep()` is a bit awkward, is it really needed? 2) Using `_Exit()` to stop a program is generally not the right way to go about this. Instead of calling `stop()` if `fopen()` succeeds, just use an `else` clause to call the `printf(INCORRRECT)`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you need a semicolon on the end of:

```
FILE *fp, *fopen(); /* ; here! */
```

You probably also want stop to match its prototype:

```
/* includes */
int stop();

/* main etc */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /* main code */
}

int stop()
{
    endwin();
    exit(0);
}
```

And for `exit()` you need `#include <stdlib.h>`

Oh and to compile this, let's say it's called `test.c`, then use `gcc -lcurses test.c -o test`. This tells gcc you want to link with libcurses.

Comment: Now I get: input1.c:37: error: redefinition of ‘stop’
input1.c:9: note: previous definition of ‘stop’ was here

Comment: Your first declaration of stop is fine `int stop();` above main. Below it, you want the function as you implemented it but with int in front. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Does that make a bit more sense? I'm guessing you edited the top "stop" not the bottom?

Comment: Ah I see. I was editing the top stop() not the bottom one. But after I edited the bottom one and tried to compile I got a similar error:
input1.c: In function ‘stop’:
input1.c:12: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
input1.c:34: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token

Comment: When that happens, you almost definitely have unbalanced parantheses, braces or a missing semi-colon somewhere. Check it carefully, line by line with proper indenting etc. It makes life a lot easier!!

Comment: Hm. All braces look okay and I checked it carefully but I can't find the source of the error :/ I'll pastie my code:http://pastie.org/1471017 I put the error I get at the bottom.

Comment: Your stop is inside your main routine. It needs to be outside it. See edit.

Comment: Also, for linking, you'll need `-lcurses`. added to answer.

Comment: I put it on the outside like it is in the edit but I still get the same exact error :/ It apparently hates me. EDIT: Oh I added -lcurses to the compiler and it worked. Thanks